# OpenOffice/Libre office xml filter import

Tags: xml, linux, command-line

I'm using OpenOffice to convert documents to pdf/xls;
Main system where usually is running Openoffice is Linux;

There(in openoffice) is such thing as XML filters;
A have package of those filters and usually to import this package I using(from launched openoffice): Tools->XML Filter settings ->open package;

It's like little converting server, but there is one problem -> system needs X server to be running;

So is there a way to import this XML filter package to Openoffice(or Libre office) from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run OpenOffice 'headless' and send scripts to it. It [looks a bit complex](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno/FAQ#How_do_I_remotely_connect_to_an_OpenOffice.org_running_on_a_different_machine.3F):

You might find this easier with LibreOffice or IBM Lotus Symphony.

Answer (score 0):

```
      libreoffice --invisible --convert-to xls --outdir 'directory where the converted files will go' 'original file'
```